# Share clickable image

Tags: react-native, share

I would like to share an image that links to a url when you click it:
I've tried adding url and base64 image to url together as an array etc. but obviously does not work. Is there away to achieve this without having to install other libraries?

**Here's my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Share } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Button, ViewContainer } from '../../../components';

class ShareIt extends Component {
  render() {
    const share = () => {
      const base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

      return (
        Share.share({
          message: 'This is a message',
          url: base64Image,
          title: 'This is the title',
          subject: 'hello'
        })
      );
    };

    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <Body>Badges will go here</Body>
        <Button
          variant="link"
          onPress={() => share()}
        >
          <Body variant="secondary">Share Badge</Body>
        </Button>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default ShareIt;
```

Comment: Hello Led. Did you ever find a solution? I am also trying to share an image with a link that opens the app. Basically an invite link that the app sends to iMessage but shows a cool app image instead of moder8://invite?group=1