# How do I share a clickable image with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have Universal Linking working. I also have the share feature working in that I can send an app link to iMessage per requirements. The issue I am trying to solve is how to share a link in the form of an image that opens the application.

I am basically trying to send an invite link to iMessage that renders a clickable image as opposed to an ugly link like moder8://invite?group=1.

A perfect example of what I am trying to do is the way TestFlight handles my invites.

[image]

To be clear, I do not need to know how the open the app with a deep link. Currently the functionality works with the exception of rendering a cool image in iMessage.

***What I have done.***

I have looked into the documentation of React Natives share feature and do not see any way to share a clickable image.

I have also searched through Stack-overflow for any related questions. The only one I can find that seems on point is the following which was never answered.

[Share clickable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658343/share-clickable-image)

Currently this is what my app does when I share the invite link which has the working functionality.

[image]

As you can see this seriously lacks a professional look and feel.

Any assist would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.